# How to add day to a string in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

My current Date format is in MM/YY. I Need to default days to my format in php.

For example:

12/2009 -> 07/12/2009

I tried this code:

```
$currdate = '07/'.$currdate;
$newFormat = date('d-M-Y',strtotime($currdate));
```

But the new format is wrong, it output 12/07/2009.

----------------- Edit -----------------------------

I have tried `**DateTime::createFromFormat**`.Since my $currdate date format has only month and year its not accepting.I am getting a fatal error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtotime` expects an american date format. Use datetime::createFromFormat instead:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $currdate);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Edited to better explanation:

When you use date with slashes(/), PHP strtotime will think it is in m/d/Y format, the american way.
If you use dash (-) it will assume d-m-Y format.
If you use dot (.) it will assume Y.m.d format.